# Pydantic ResponseValidationError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Ранее в синхронном sqlalchemy возвращал обьект и pydantic успешно делал валидацию, но как это сделать с async sqlalchemy?
Пишу тестовый пример для изучения.

вот сам код.

```
class Teachers(Base):
    __tablename__ = "teachers"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(length=30))


class OrmBaseModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

class TeachersResponse(OrmBaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str


@router.post("/add_teacher", response_model=TeachersResponse)
async def add_teacher(name: str):
    session = await get_session()
    # result = await session.execute(insert(Teachers).values(name = name))

    new_teacher = Teachers(name=name)
    session.add(new_teacher)
    await session.commit()
    return new_teacher
```

После вызова роутера /add_teacher выдает ошибку валидации, что не так делаю ?

raise ResponseValidationError(
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError

Comment: Ну вы возвращаете объект `Teachers`, а в `response_model` пишете `TeachersResponse`. По идее достаточно `response_model=TeachersResponse` заменить на `response_model=Teachers`. Чтобы не падало c `response_model=TeachersResponse`, по идее нужно сделать, чтобы `Teachers` наследовался от `TeachersResponse`